# Insert result from one insert query into another insert

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, sql-insert, common-table-expression

I have two psotgres tables. Table 1 has userid as primary key. Table 2 uses the userid as a foreign key,  I need to insert data into table 1 and 2. I want to do it all in one statement
If the insert into table 2 fails I need the insert into table 1 two be deleted.

```
INSERT into table1 (userid,email)Values(12,"example@gmail.com") RETURNING userid

INSERT into table2(userid,name,address)Values(12,"Joe","123 test Dr")
```

How can I do this in one statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the first `insert` in a `with` clause. If you know all values in advance, you don't even need `returning`:

```
with ins as (
    insert into table1 (userid, email)
    values(12,'example@gmail.com') 
)
insert into table2 (userid, name, address)
values(12, 'Joe', '123 test Dr')
```

On the other hand, if `userid` is an autogenerated value, then you can return it from the CTE, and use it in the other insert as follows:

```
with ins as (
    insert into table1 (email)
    values('example@gmail.com') 
    returning userid
)
insert into table2 (userid, name, address)
select userid, 'joe', '123 test Dr'
from ins
```

Side note: use single quotes for literal strings. Double quotes are used for identifiers (column names, table names, and so on).

Comment: does the first insert not happen if the second insert fails?

Comment: @JuliaT: basically, yes, it is all or nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much!